# Why Akka Remote Traffic Going Over UDP?

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

I am setting up a Akka Cluster on Kubernetes, but I am having trouble with firewall rules, since cluster / remote traffic is going over UDP. My understanding is that traffic should be going over TCP, as per remote configuration below.

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = "cluster"
  }
  remote {
    artery {
      enabled = on
      transport = tcp
      canonical.port = 2552
    }
  }
}
```

I am seeing this when tracing traffic in one of the Kubernetes nodes.

```
tcpdump -nn -i any udp

13:30:34.503659 IP 192.168.122.52.47831 > 192.168.122.51.8472
IP 10.244.4.0.47044 > 10.244.3.42.2552
13:30:34.503768 IP 192.168.122.51.42334 > 192.168.122.52.8472
IP 10.244.3.42.2552 > 10.244.4.0.47044
```

How can we avoid traffic on UDP ports?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured this is related to flannel overlay network.

https://github.com/coreos/coreos-kubernetes/blob/master/Documentation/kubernetes-networking.md